# defining 3 regulators controlled by same GPIO pin in linux devicetree (arm)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-tree

I have a board for which I'm fixing/writing the device tree for, based on the rk3288 (rockchip). In the file there are currently the following definitions for three seperate regulators:

```
    dovdd_1v8: dovdd-1v8-regulator {
            compatible = "regulator-fixed";
            enable-active-high;
            gpio = <&gpio0 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&dvp_pwr>;
            regulator-name = "dovdd_1v8";
            regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
            regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
            vin-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    };

    vcc28_dvp: vcc28-dvp-regulator {
            compatible = "regulator-fixed";
            enable-active-high;
            gpio = <&gpio0 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&dvp_pwr>;
            regulator-name = "vcc28_dvp";
            regulator-min-microvolt = <2800000>;
            regulator-max-microvolt = <2800000>;
            vin-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    };

    af_28: af_28-regulator {
            compatible = "regulator-fixed";
            enable-active-high;
            gpio = <&gpio0 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&dvp_pwr>;
            regulator-name = "af_28";
            regulator-min-microvolt = <2800000>;
            regulator-max-microvolt = <2800000>;
            vin-supply = <&vcc_io>;
    };
```

The problem is that the kernel complains that it can't assign the same GPIO pin to these 3 regulators. In the schematic for the board the regulators are controlled by the same GPIO pin.

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks!
B

EDIT: here is the error message I see on the serial console:

```
[    0.270507] rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: pin gpio0-11 already requested 
by dovdd-1v8-regulator; cannot claim for vcc28-dvp-regulator
[    0.270570] rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: pin-11 (vcc28-dvp-regulator) status -22
[    0.270611] rockchip-pinctrl pinctrl: could not request pin 11 (gpio0-11) from group dvp-pwr  on device rockchip-pinctrl
[    0.270663] reg-fixed-voltage vcc28-dvp-regulator: Error applying setting, reverse things back
```

[image: cif power regulators]

Comment: Study the kernel code.  **drivers/regulator/core.c** mentions that "same GPIO pin can be shared among regulators".

Comment: @sawdust then why do I get an error message?

Comment: @b20000 Which kernel version are you using?

Comment: @sam protsenko 4.4

Comment: @sam protsenko see github.com/rockchip-linux branch release-4.4

Comment: @b20000 Was thinking maybe your kernel outdated. But no, it already has the change mentioned by sawdust: [here](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/kernel/blob/release-4.4/drivers/regulator/core.c#L1878)

Comment: The regulator core seems capable of enabling multiple regulators by just one GPIO.  It's the fixed regulator driver that is using GPIO resource control that's the road block.  This is discussed in this [Linux ARM kernel thread](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2014-June/267938.html).  Note that the gpio attribute in the fixed regulator DT node is optional, but that does not activate the sharing.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for the comments. What is the solution here giventhe state of the kernel code as it is?

Answer (score 1):

The regulator subsystem allows a single GPIO to enable more than one regulator.
I can find no code in [fixed.c](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/kernel/blob/release-4.4/drivers/regulator/fixed.c) or [core.c](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/kernel/blob/release-4.4/drivers/regulator/core.c) that would inhibit several regulators to share one enabling GPIO.

Now that you have added the salient error message, the issue is clearer.
The error messages that you are getting are not from the GPIO resource management, but rather from the pinctrl subsystem.
The likely cause of this is improper declarations of the pinctrl group for each regulator. 
(You have not posted that portion of your Device Tree.)
Hence you get a pinctrl allocation error, which is not the same as a GPIO allocation error.
(The pinctrl subsystem is at a lower level than GPIO management, and can allocate pins for peripheral functions, aka pin multiplexing, as well as for GPIO.)

I'm not sure what the proper fix in the DT should be.
Assuming that there is just one pinctrl group declared for the enabling GPIO, you can try using it only once in one regulator node.  IOW remove the pinctrl attributes in the other two regulators.